# Issue in using Preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace "ing" from the right side of the word, but the code below is also replacing other characters.

```
$temp = "gameing"; //incorrect spellings for test//
$temp = preg_replace('/(\w)ing\b/','',$temp);
echo $temp;
```

Is giving output `"gam"`, instead of `game`.

Comment: what would be the output of `Painting  and Gaming`?

Comment: Use `$temp = preg_replace('/\w\King\b/','',$temp);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the character before "ing", you can put it into replacement:

```
<?php
$temp = "gameing";
$temp = preg_replace('/(\w)ing\b/','$1',$temp);
//-> game
echo $temp;
```

Comment: preg_replace('/(\w)ing\b/','$1',$temp); $1?

Comment: @AgnosticS $1 is the reference to symbols in brackets. "e" in the this case.